# C++ output screen disappears

Tags: c++

Why does my C++ output screen disappear immediately?  I'm a beginner in cpp.  Can anyone help me to find the problem please?

Comment: Although I'm guessing Windows with Visual Studio, please confirm what operating system and compiler you are using.

Comment: probably because you're `main` functions returns. Try adding a `cin` command to the last line. That said, it's bascially impossible to figure out what you're trying to ask from what you've posted.

Comment: Indiv its basic cpp and not visual studio

Comment: @ARUNRAJ How should we know what actually hapoens, without seeing your code, or how you run the compiledf result?? My crystal balls are out for maintenance today, sorry.

Comment: @indiv That's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ:  No it's not.

Comment: @indiv In which way? Elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

You should either launch your application inside of a terminal, or add a line of code that waits for the input in order for the window to not close. E.g. add in the end of the function `main` a line:

```
    std::cin.get();
```

And also add at beginning of the file the include that holds that function.

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: I actually prefer, setting a breakpoint in my debugger, instead of adding code just purposed to hold a terminal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I actually prefer launch a terminal app from a shell to see an output ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but I did, it is the first words in the post. As for the code to hold a terminal — well, they just a beginner, and perhaps with Windows as an operating system, so that is the best point to start, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer since there can be many things that can cause your output box to close immediately.  First try having a cout statement and then a cin statement.  Something like:

```
cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
cin>>input>>endl;
```

Also make sure to have the necessary include statement at the top and whatever you want to return at the bottom.

```
#include<iostream>

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have said that you are beginner in C++, you should keep in mind ,three major things while coding in C++. You've mentioned that your screen disappears , then following things you should try.

1). in C++ conventionally main returns value of type int.And the format of your program should be like...

```
int main()
{
  -------
//body of your program
  -------
  return 0;
}
```

If the function returns 0, that means it ran successfully.

2). You have to inlcude `#include<iostream>` on the top of your program.

3).check whether the IDE you are using is compatibale to your operating system or not.

Hope this will help you.